# Why is Mobilefirst 7.0 iOS App with Push Notifications Enabled Crashing?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting a exception in my iOS App(generated using Mobilefirst 7) which occurs after I login. The app tries to connect to the Mobilefirst Server and try to register for push notifications. The crash happens at this moment.
I am seeing a IBM ticket which was raised on this. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI42699

I am getting the same exact issue. 
The exception is

> : -[__NSCFBoolean stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1987b22f0 developerones-iPad
>   MyAppName[207] : *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception
>   in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionLi
>   stener: delegate:  -[__NSCFBoolean
>   stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x1987b22f0

There is a solution in this ticket but I could not find a file named ios-gap.js. Has anyone faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a product bug.
This is as suggested by the APAR you have linked to.

The APAR is fixed.
What you need to do is to make sure you are using the latest MobileFirst Platform 7.0 iFix by visiting IBM Fix Central and download the updated Studio, then re-build your project and verify that the crash no longer occurs.

Comment: Thanks Idan for the answer. Will get the fix and try it out.